# having issues adding array of dates to firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Working on an app that takes user selections on the calendar. I'm taking the selected range of dates and adding them to an array. The array is stored in dates. I'm having an issue uploading the array into firestore. I keep getting an error message when I upload this.state.markedDates.

first function gets the date ranges

```
getDates(s, e){
//below code is getting start date and end date plus placing the range in an array for upload into firebase. 
var grabDates = [];
const start = moment(s).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
const end = moment(e).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
const range = moment.range(s, e)
const arrayOfDates = Array.from(range.by('days'))
arrayOfDates.map(m => {
      var dates = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      grabDates.push(dates);
});
this.markedDates = grabDates
```

}

Then I upload to firebase using the function below.

```
confirm(){
if (this.markedDates == null){
  alert('Please choose your dates');
} else {
    var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var newData = db.collection('Calendars').doc(currentUser).collection('Dates');
    newData.add({
      bookedDates: [this.state.markedDates]
      }).then(function(docRef){
      console.log(docRef);
      }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Post error message

Comment: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported